# Reading a specific type of file on bucket S3

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, databricks, bucket

I tryng to read a specific type of file on bucket S3 by databricks, but I'm not finding a away to do that, if you could help me, I'll appreciate a lot. Thanks

Case - OK:

```
df = spark.read.load('/mnt/dataset/json/file.json', format='json')
df.display()
```

Case that I trying to do, NOT OK:

```
df = spark.read.load('/mnt/dataset/json/*.json', format='json')
df.display()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spark, but I wonder whether you can use `pathGlobFilter` as shown on [Generic File Source Options - Spark 3.2.0 Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html)?

Comment: How is the first approach result compared to the second approach? Is the file not being picked up by spark in second approach? I think you can use `pathGlobFilter` as @JohnRotenstein mentioned and update the code to `df = spark.read.load('/mnt/dataset/json', format='json', pathGlobFilter='*.json')`

Comment: Thanks, John and Tax Evader, I actually figured out using another strategy, I've created a DateTime variable for my process just do all the ingestions reading this file by day, because It comes only one file daily, the other approach that I was trying to do, basically my process would do the ingestion process taking the all JSON files.